# Doing health check on port 443 from bash

Tags: webserver

I have requested my network colleague to setup F5 Global Traffic Manager (GTM) for my webservers at 443 port. But he has reported the GTM has not received any reponse from my webservers. But I know the servers are running at 443 port because customers are getting response.

I wanted to test myself from web servers at command line. But the server servers do not have curl, not the rught modules in python. So I resorted to bash. But even for google.com I do not get any response from 443, I get it port 80 though. What am I missing? Is response from 443 port expected?

```
root@VDIkali:~/python# { echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r" >&3; cat <&3 ; } 3<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80|head -2
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 14:40:00 GMT

root@VDIkali:~/python# { echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r" >&3; cat <&3 ; } 3<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/443|head -2
-------------NO RESPONSE------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure that writing to `/dev/tcp/www.google.com/443` is going to handle the HTTPS protocol properly, which is why you wouldn't get any answer from a confused server.

Answer (score 1):

As 443 is the https port, any machine that you want to use for health checks needs to be able to make https (SSL/TLS) connections. `curl` would indeed be one of the easiest to use, is installing it on the health checking machine really not an option?

If it is actually not available, giving meaningful help here isn't easy, as we don't know what SSL connection tools might be available on that machine.